# Are there any real immortals - since that would contradict Bhagavad Gita 2-27?

Tags: immortality

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 02, Verse 27

English:

> Jaatasya hi dhruvo mrtyur, dhruvam janma mrtasya cha
> Tasmaat aparihaaryerthe, na tvam sochitum arhasi

Sanskrit:

> जातस्य हि ध्रुबो मृत्युर, ध्रुवम जन्म मृतस्य च
> तस्मात अपरि हारयेरर्थे, न त्वम शोचितुम अर्हसि

Selected word meaning:

> jaatasya - one who has taken birth, hi - certainly, dhruvah - a fact, mrityuh - death, dhruvam - also a fact, janma - birth, mirtasya - one who is dead, cha - also, tasmaat - therefore, aparihaarye - for the inevitable, arthe - in the matter of, na - do not, tvam - you, sochitum - to lament , arhasi - deserve

Translation:

> For the one who is born, death is certain and for one who is dead, birth is certain. Therefore, you should not lament for the inevitable situation

Brahma also says to either Ravana or Hiranyakashipu that he cannot grant the boon of immortality.

So do the "immortals" like Hanuman,Vibhishana et al just live for a long time and are not truly immortal?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct. Vibhishana and Hanumanji live for a very long time. Vibhishana reference can be found in scriptures. Hanumanji is however not found in current versions but is there in Sri Vaishnava tradition. Sorry, Hanumanji is there in Ramayana as far as i remember wait wait

Answer (score 3):

Yes the statement on immortality sounds absolutely correct. Talking specifically about Vibhishana and Hanumanji, the both of them were blessed to stay on earth till the end of the kalpa or end of creation i.e. a very long time.

#### Vibhishana

To Vibhishana, Bhagavan says:

> “**As long as people exist, O Mighty Lord of the Rakshasas, do you remain in Lanka. As long as the moon and sun continue to shine on the earth, as long as they speak of me in the world, so long shall thine empire endure**; this is the will of your friend, do you obey! Govern your people according to justice and do not question this further. One thing more I wish to say to you, O Mighty Monarch of the Rakshasas, do you worship the Divinity of the House of Ikshvaku, the Guide of the Universe, Shri Jagannatha, whom the Devas themselves with their leaders perpetually adore.” 
> -*Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam, Uttarakāṇḍa, Chapter 108, verses 27-32*

It is believed that Vibhishana is still alive and following the above advice of Bhagavan, comes to offer his prayers to Bhagavan at Srirangam.

#### Hanumanji

To Hanumanji, he says:

> “Resign thyself to continuing to live, do not render my will void. **As long as my story is told in the world, O Foremost of Monkeys, so long mayest you be enjoy**, while obeying my words!”
> -*Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam, Uttarakāṇḍa, Chapter 108, verses 33-34*

And interesting thing to note is the time period for which Ramakatha would stay on in the world. Brahmaji blesses Valmiki saying the following about Ramakatha:

> Do you render into verse the sacred and delightful deeds of Rama. **O Sage, as long as the mountains and rivers remain on the earth, so long will the story of Shri Rama endure**. So long as the story of Rama endures, so long shalt you abide in the higher regions.”
> -*Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam, Bālakāṇḍa, Chapter 2, verses 37-38*

Well Valmiki too has been mentioned here as having a very long life. The interpretation from the above is that Valmiki’s Ramakatha will live on till the end of creation and consequently, so will Hanumanji.

There is a famous verse on Hanumanji which goes: yatra yatra raghunāthakīrtanam tatra tatra krtamastakāñjalim … or wherever the glories of Bhagavan are sung, there Hanumanji comes and bows down with his hands folded.

So yes they will live for a very very long time. And yes, जातस्य हि ध्रुबो मृत्युर्ध्रुवं जन्म मृतस्य च except if they have been given moksha.